# Set crystal report textobject bold at runtime using C#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I'm updating text objects in my Crystal report in the C# code like this,

```
ReportDocument rptDoc = new ReportDocument();
rptDoc.Load(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\Test.rpt");
TextObject txtTest = (TextObject)rptDoc.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["txtTest"];
txtTest.Text = "Test";
```

Now I want to bold the text in "txtTest" text object.

I'm looking for something like this,

```
txtTest.Font.Bold = true;
```

But unfortunately it is read-only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have found a solution.

```
System.Drawing.Font font1 = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold);
txtTest.ApplyFont(font1);
```